# CasperJS tester module output to csv instead of command line

Tags: javascript, csv, automated-tests, casperjs

Using a CasperJS test module, is there a way to output the assert outputs to a CSV instead of a command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can write your own assertion serializer. You can collect the information using the [events "success", "skipped" and "failed"](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/019659c6ddbd0ae3df0966bf262b3d02db43b5d7/modules/tester.js#L1383-L1411). Then you can append it directly to your CSV file using PhantomJS' fs module ([`fs.write()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/method/write.html)).

```
var fs = require('fs');
casper.test.on("success", function(result){
    fs.write("file", "success;"+result.message+"\n", "a");
});
casper.test.on("skipped", function(result){
    fs.write("file", "skipped;"+result.message+"\n", "a");
});
casper.test.on("fail", function(result){
    fs.write("file", "fail;"+result.message+"\n", "a");
});
```